# How to install Ansys?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

I know officially it's just supported on Suse and Red Hat, but it looks like some people are running it on Ubuntu successfully.
I tried to install both fluids and preppost, but both fail with the same error:

```
>>>--------------------------------------->
ANSYS installation: Mi. Sep 19 22:49:46 2018
Revision: Release 19.2

   ###### Error #######
   Error executing configuration script '/usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigRSM.sh'
   '"/usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigRSM.sh"  -installdir "/usr/ansys_inc" -rev 192 -dotrev 19.2 -scripttosource "/usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/ConfigCommon.tcl" -sourcedir "/tmp/ans_install_tmp23639" -os_lang en-us -install -skip_file_associations ' terminated after 1 attempts with the following error(s): 
       Unknown error
   Exit Code: 0
   readlink: UngÃ¼ltige Option -- p
   âreadlink --helpâ liefert weitere Informationen.
   dirname: fehlender Operand
   âdirname --helpâ liefert weitere Informationen.
   dirname: fehlender Operand
   âdirname --helpâ liefert weitere Informationen.
   dirname: fehlender Operand
   âdirname --helpâ liefert weitere Informationen.
   dirname: fehlender Operand
   âdirname --helpâ liefert weitere Informationen.
   dirname: fehlender Operand
   âdirname --helpâ liefert weitere Informationen.
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/RSM/Config/tools/linux/rsmconfig: 26: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/RSM/Config/tools/linux/rsmconfig: /Framework/bin/Linux64/runwb2: not found/usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/libans.common.clrhostmonou.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/libans.common.controlsu.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/libans.graphics.controlsu.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/libans.graphics.graphutilityu.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/commonfiles/configs/linx64/config/AnsConfigWB.sh: 170: [: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/dll/linx64/*ud.so: unexpected operator
   /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/.workbench: 1: /usr/ansys_inc/v192/aisol/../commonfiles/MainWin/linx64/mw/setup-mwuser: rpm: not found
   ﻿
>>>--------------------------------------->
```

I'm on ubuntu 18.04 64bit and try to install ansys 19.2 academic edition

Comment: There's a series of commentaries on this at [https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/ansys/199190-ansys-18-2-ubuntu-16-04-installation-guide.html](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/ansys/199190-ansys-18-2-ubuntu-16-04-installation-guide.html)